Why is getting silver badges so much harder with questions than with answers?
Getting silver badges is so much harder with questions than with answers.
And I think that is mainly because of the silver 'Enlightened' badge.
Examples
If you look at the top users at PSE, you'll notice the difference in silver badges.
For example, people who answers much more than asking questions, have about an even number of silver and bronze badges:

@Deusovi, who has 532 silver badges, and 622 bronze badges. (338x 'Enlightened')
@MOehm, who has 224 silver badges, 285 bronze badges. (142x 'Enlightened')

Compare that to people who ask much more questions than giving answers:

@Jafe, who has only 165 silver badges, and 646 bronze badges.
@Prim3numbah, who has only 22 silver badges, and 216 bronze badges.

(These examples are not personal, and they have certainly earned each badge!)
What happens most of the time?
It is really hard to get a good number of views. From personal experience, getting about 1k-2k is max. for a ordinary question. For a good question, that leads to 10-20 upvotes. Result? 2 bronze badges: 1 for 1k views (if lucky), and 1 for 10 upvotes.
Someone who answers the question, has about the same number of upvotes. And with 10-20 upvotes, you get 1 silver and 1 bronze badge: 1 for 10 upvotes and accept, and 1 for 10 upvotes.
A simple example from myself (not to brag, just an example):
This puzzle is delicious. It's a simple puzzle, with a simple answer. Currently 217 views, 10 upvotes on the question, 10 upvotes on the answer. I got 1 bronze badge, @BeastlyGerbil got 1 silver badge.
PSE specific
I think this is PSE specific, because PSE is one of the few sites where people spend time to craft a good question. Most of the other sites, people just want answers on things they don't know/understand.
Should there be a solution to this? Or are we just going to leave it as it is? Any other thoughts about this?

On other sites, if you don't spend time on your question, then it will likely be downvoted. It takes time and effort to write a well-formed question.

"PSE is one of the few sites where people spend time to craft a good question. Most of the other sites, people just want answers on things they don't know/understand." and yet the front page is currently full of posts in double-digit scores that consist solely of a short riddle or puzzle copied straight from another book or website. There is no crafting there at all. Meanwhile a significant number of questions on other sites provide comparative background, identify their process, and seek clarification of one minor issue. ... 1/2

2/2 ... Given that you have effectively no presence on any other site in the network, this is purely a gratuitous insult to dozens of communities founded and based on your own ignorance. I strongly advise removing it.

@Nij The riddles with many views (almost all of them are at least 6 years old), are exceptions. And if you have a silver badge for 25 upvotes, the answer has most likely 2 silver badges: 1 for 25 upvotes and the extra one for (again) 'Enlightened'.

@Nij, but maybe I should remove the paragraph about other sites, I am not sure. That doesn't change the overall point.

I have never mentioned views, that's irrelevant. I am not talking about posts from years ago, I am talking about the front page, the recent and recently active posts, those created within the last week, which are gaining double digit scores. This also suggests you are basing a call to action on the subjective impression that questions aren't earning as many badges, let alone that this is a problem and not by design.

@Lezzup Your words, “PSE is one of the few sites where people spend time to craft a good question.” could easily be considered insulting to people who primarily use other sites.  I agree with user Nij and recommend you delete these words.
